# Funciones y parámetros

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo una duda que realmente no sé cómo explicar pero trataré de hacerlo, espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo dos funciones, la **primera** `selectTareasP` será la conexión a la base de datos y a su vez recibirá el parámetro `$proyecto_id` el cuál utilizaré en la **segunda** `getTareasPendientes`(**este método no puedo modificarlo**), en esta otra tengo tres parámetros, el primero es la conexión a la base de datos (`$conex`) el segundo es opcional y no lo utilizaré y el tercero que es el que me interesa es un arreglo para aplicar filtros a la consulta, como se ve en el codigo, de momento el único filtro es el `proyecto_id` el cuál obtiene mediante una consulta, pero yo no lo haré de esta forma, ya que yo ya recibo el `id` de dicho proyecto, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo mando ese `$proyecto_id` como parámetro para `$tPs = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $proyecto_id);`

**tarea_model.php**

```
    public static function selectTareasP(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) { 

        $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();   
        $tPs = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $proyecto_id);
        foreach ($tPs as $ids) {    
            $id = $ids['id'];
            //Tarea::cancelarTarea($conex, $id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve arreglo de tareas PENDIENTES asociadas al Empleado.
     * @param  SafeMySQL $db    Conex. a BD
     * @param  integer    $idEmp ID del Empleado (opcional)
     * @param  array    $aFiltro Arreglo para aplicar filtros personalizados a la consulta:
     *                           ftroLimit: valore entero como limite para reg a devolver
     *                           proyecto_id: ID de proyecto
     * @return array           [description]
     */
    public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $aFiltro=array()){
        $ftroLimit = $proyecto_id = '';
        if(!empty($aFiltro) && is_array($aFiltro)){//condiciones esperadas
            if(isset($aFiltro['ftroLimit']) && $aFiltro['ftroLimit'] > 0){//se envia un valor entero como limite
                $ftroLimit = ' LIMIT '.$aFiltro['ftroLimit'];
            }
            if(isset($aFiltro['proyecto_id'])) $proyecto_id = $aFiltro['proyecto_id'];//se espera ID de proyecto
        }
        $sql = "SELECT t1.id, t1.solicitud, t2.responsable FROM Tareas t1
        INNER JOIN tareas_emp t2 ON t1.id = t2.tareas_id
        LEFT JOIN Proyectos t3 ON t1.proyecto_id = t3.id
        WHERE t1.estatus = 'Pendiente' ";
        if($idEmp > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t2.empleado_id = $idEmp ";
        }
        if($proyecto_id > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t3.id = $proyecto_id ";
        }
        $sql.= $ftroLimit;
        $data = $db->getAll($sql);
        return $data;
    }
```

Se agradece su ayuda(:

Comment: Por lo que dices, tendrías que modificar totalmente este método: `public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $aFiltro=array()){`, no solamente los parámetros que recibe, sino el manejo dentro del mismo. Quedaría más o menos así: `public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $proyecto_id){...` luego, por supuesto, todo el cuerpo del método debe ser modificado, quitando todo lo relativo a `$aFiltro` y adaptándolo a lo que quieres hacer en el método con `$proyecto_id`

Comment: La cosa es que no tengo permitido modificar el código que ya existe y mi jefe dijo utilizara ese método `getTareasPendientes` así como está, Yo ya había resuelto esto por medio de una consulta pero me dijo que no.

Comment: Ohhh, haberlo dicho de antemano, es un dato muy importante para una posible respuesta. Entonces simplemente construyes tu array pasando dentro de él el valor de `$proyecto_id`. Ahora modifico la respuesta. Perooo... ¿el método `selectTareasP` sí lo puedes modificar o tampoco?

Comment: Una disculpa, se me olvidó mencionarlo, y si, ese método si puedo modificarlo.

Comment: Verifica la respuesta editada. Así debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

Dado que como has comentado `getTareasPendientes` no se puede modificar, lo revertimos a su estado original, y modificamos el método `selectTareasP`:

```
public static function selectTareasP(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) { 

    $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();
    /* 
     * Creamos un array con proyecto_id para pasarlo a getTareasPendientes
    */
    $arrProyecto=array("proyecto_id"=>$proyecto_id);   
    $tPs = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex, '', $arrProyecto); //aquí ya no pasas $id_proyecto, sino el array antes creado
    foreach ($tPs as $ids) {    
        $id = $ids['id'];
        //Tarea::cancelarTarea($conex, $id);
    }
}



public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $proyecto_id){
    $ftroLimit = $proyecto_id = '';
    if(!empty($aFiltro) && is_array($aFiltro)){//condiciones esperadas
        if(isset($aFiltro['ftroLimit']) && $aFiltro['ftroLimit'] > 0){//se envia un valor entero como limite
            $ftroLimit = ' LIMIT '.$aFiltro['ftroLimit'];
        }
        if(isset($aFiltro['proyecto_id'])) $proyecto_id = $aFiltro['proyecto_id'];//se espera ID de proyecto
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT t1.id, t1.solicitud, t2.responsable FROM Tareas t1
    INNER JOIN tareas_emp t2 ON t1.id = t2.tareas_id
    LEFT JOIN Proyectos t3 ON t1.proyecto_id = t3.id
    WHERE t1.estatus = 'Pendiente' ";
    if($idEmp > 0){
        $sql.= "AND t2.empleado_id = $idEmp ";
    }
    if($proyecto_id > 0){
        $sql.= "AND t3.id = $proyecto_id ";
    }

    $sql.= $ftroLimit;

    $data = $db->getAll($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

---

> **Nota:** Si las variables que intervienen en la consulta son tomadas desde fuentes externas, tus consultas son vulnerables a la Inyección
>   SQL, se recomienda usar consultas preparadas.

Comment: Si funciona, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya funcionado @PalomaAG. Saludos.